# max execution time reached instead of throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have an application in Laravel 10. this application hosted in Apache (not using php artisan serve). every time there is an error, the page loading untill it reach max_execution_time, and there's nothing usefull showing on that page. this made it hard to debug what causing the error?
anybody know how to fix this? I am sorry if I posted it in wrong forum

[image]

Comment: Your application probably is just running in circles somewhere, until it times out. The trick is to find out where this looping happens. First you need to find a way to reliably cause this timeout error. Then you can insert echoes or exits in the code until the timeout doesn't occur or you can see where the loop is. Once you've located the loop you need to find out why it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Check PHP Error Logs:
First, check your PHP error logs. These logs may contain more detailed information about what's causing the issue. By default, PHP error logs are typically located in a file called error.log or php_error.log in your web server's logs directory. You can configure the PHP error log location in your php.ini file.

Increase max_execution_time:
If your application legitimately needs more time to execute certain tasks, you can increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini file or in your Apache configuration. Be cautious when doing this, as excessively long execution times can lead to performance issues. It's better to optimize your code if possible.

Comment: thank you for replying. I checked my web server log, and found the same exact words as in the frontend. if there is no error, the app does not need several minutes to load, just a few seconds.